# Generating templated HTML documents (unrelated CSS files) from ReactJS single page app

Tags: css, reactjs

We have recently switched to a React SPA site. From the old site, we have some documents (invoices, quotes) that we generate as HTML files that we then print as PDFs. These templates are designed by a third party and have their own separate CSS files that have nothing to do with our React SPA's CSS. After the shift to React, I added some of the templates as React-friendly modules and converted their CSS to JSS. It worked but only partially as a lot of styles are overridden by the React SPA's CSS so the results are not consistent. We don't have the resources to redo all templates from scratch and this isn't something that we should be doing anyway - ideally, we want to be able to just load in the CSS that we get from the designer and only play around with the HTML/JSX (happy to use a tool to convert CSS to JSS but no custom editing). Is there a way to somehow ignore/unload all app CSS when loading a specific page, and only use a specific CSS/JSS file (in our case makeStyles), then bring it back to normal when another page is viewed?

Comment: I came up with an (ugly & temporary) solution to do it that suits my needs: when clicking on 'generate html', I launch a new window which initiates another instance of the single page app. While loading the page, I clear all existing styles (except for ones with the data-meta attribute of 'makeStyles' that are generated by me for that specific page). This loads the app only with those styles. Inefficient but works for now. Would be nice to see a more elegant solution.

Comment: This is the code for the above:
    document.querySelectorAll('style,link[rel="stylesheet"]').forEach(item => {
        if (!(item.getAttribute('data-meta') === 'makeStyles')){
            item.remove()
        };
    });